# Setting up logging config in .Net library project

Tags: logging, nlog

I have class library (that I would be distributing) which has a log appender that writes some metrics to a specific location. I have the appenders configured in a csharp file

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        const string layout = @"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}(${threadid})|${logger}|${message}";

        //File appender
        var fileTarget = new FileTarget
        {
            Layout = layout,
            FileName = "${basedir}/logs/Desktop.Log",
            MaxArchiveFiles = 5,
            ArchiveAboveSize = 5000000
        };

        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
        var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(fileRule);           

        //Activate
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Firstly, is it a good idea to activate log manager in a library project that I am planning to distribute? I am doing it this way as my library **needs** to log data to a file and it should not be turned off by the consuming App

If the consuming app uses the same logging library and if it replaces my config with their implementation, would it not overwrite the rules that I had defined in my library? I want to make sure that the library continues to log data to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a LogFactory which would protect my library's logging config from being overwritten by a consuming Application

Here is how I create an instance of LogFactory

```
class NLogManager
{
    public static readonly LogFactory Instance = new LogFactory(GetConfig());

    private static LoggingConfiguration GetConfig()
    {
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        const string layout = @"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}(${threadid})|${logger}|${message}";

        //Console appender
        var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget
        {
            Layout = layout,
            UseDefaultRowHighlightingRules = true
        };
        config.AddTarget("PPH.ConsoleTarget", consoleTarget);
        var consoleRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(consoleRule);

        return config;
    }
```

And I invoke the logger by calling the Instance method on the log manager

```
var logger = Instance.GetLogger(component);
logger.debug("hello world!");
```